# Keyboard hotkeys for direction + two clicks [slither.io]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I am using AutoHotKey to add hotkeys to slither.io. In this game player has two inputs:
Mouse click events (hold down LMB, release LMB, press RMB)
The direction to mouse pointer from center of the screen (note that on 1920x1080 screen mouse coordinates {0,540} and {480,540} have the same effect because the direction is the same).

In vanilla version player can just use mouse alone. Assigning "d" to LMB and "f" to RMB helps a lot because it is a lot harder to precisely move pointer while holding LMB down.
Second step would be to bind mouse position to a keyboard. Slow, but precise positioning -> use mouse. Fast, but inaccurate positioning - use keyboard.

I've experimented with several setups. "WASD" isn't accurate enough. "WERSFXCV" allows for 8 directions and is quite natural. However, I ran out of fingers for LMB and RMB. Plus, I have unused "D".

What is the best way to precisely control the direction with a keyboard and have two more hotkeys for acceleration and slowing down?

---

LMB = Left mouse button
RMB = Right mouse button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In slither you don't really need two buttons.  You can set `d` for this.
Odd `d` causes LMB down. Even `d` + LMB up or RMB press.
Then you can use `wersfxcv` for direction and `d` for acceleration.

Comment: Great point. I will try.